# After moving my PostgreSQL data folder to a new disk, the cluster ownser shows as "unknown"

Tags: postgresql, data

I moved my PostreSQL cluster data folder to a new disk and after restarting the server I noticed that `pg_lsclusters` returns "unknown" as the cluster owner rather than "postgres" as expected (the cluster seems to work ok anyway).

[image]

I searched around and found no hint on what could be the cause and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What steps did you take in order move the folder to a new disk?

Comment: @jjanes I think I did the right steps: mounted a new share, created a folder, granted the ownership of it to the postgres user and rsynced (-a) the data folder into the new one.

Comment: While the database was live!?  Based on that description, pg_lsclusters should still be reporting the old location, as you haven't done anything to update its metadata.